# Is it ok accessing [UIApplication sharedApplication] from background thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, ui-thread

While working on `Objective-C`, I need to get the `protectedDataAvailable` status possibly inside some background threads.

```
- (BOOL) isProtected {
    BOOL protectedDataAvailable = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] isProtectedDataAvailable];
    return protectedDataAvailable;
}
```

As I am accessing `[UIApplication sharedApplication]`, I suspect that the code block should run in main queue. **How can I do so?**

I was thinking to change it like,

```
- (BOOL) isProtected {

    BOOL protectedDataAvailable = NO;

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        protectedDataAvailable = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] isProtectedDataAvailable];
    });

    return protectedDataAvailable;
}
```

**Question 1:** Should the code be run inside main queue/ UI Thread?

**Question 2:** If yes, will my changed code resolve the problem? or is there any better approach?

The reason I am asking this question is, even if I access the `UIApplication` on **main queue synchronously**, when the block gets called from `main thread` it gets crash. How can I deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question 1: Should the code be run inside main queue/ UI Thread?

Definitely yes because if you run your app with the main thread checker on Xcode will highlight calls `UIApplication sharedApplication` as issues when accessed from a background thread

> Question 2: If yes, will my changed code resolve the problem?

Unless you call `isProtected` from the main thread yes.

> or is there any better approach?

I would stick to something like this:

```
- (BOOL)isProtected
{
    __block BOOL protectedDataAvailable = NO;

    if ([NSThread isMainThread])
    {
        protectedDataAvailable = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] isProtectedDataAvailable];
    }
    else
    {
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            protectedDataAvailable = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] isProtectedDataAvailable];
        });
    }

    return protectedDataAvailable;
}
```

As Alejandro Ivan pointed in the comment instead of using a semaphore you can resort to simple `dispatch_sync`

Comment: Why use `dispatch_async()` with a semaphore instead of just doing `dispatch_sync()`? Pretty sure handling semaphores manually is expensive. I would use `- (BOOL)isProtected { __block BOOL protectedDataAvailable = NO; dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ protectedDataAvailable = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] isProtectedDataAvailable]; }); return protectedDataAvailable; }`

Comment: @AlejandroIván I agree. Simply dispatch_sync is definitely an option with at least less code or even (which I'm not sure of) less overhead

Comment: The main difference is that GCD queues don't use locks (so they're a single thread access), but semaphores do use them (although lightweight mutex locks). That makes semaphores compatible with multi threading. For a normal UI app, there's -probably- no need for semaphores.

Comment: @AndreyChernukha If I use `dispatch_sync` I just need to remove lines related to semaphore, right? It would be helpful if you update your code for using `dispatch_sync`.