# Performing selector on Main thread from the current thread inside performAndWait block of a NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have an `NSManagedObjectContext` which is initialised from [newBackgroundContext](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentcontainer/1640581-newbackgroundcontext) of the `persistentContainer` as following:

```
managedContext = coreDataStack.persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
```

This is how `persistentContainer` looks like:

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "myXCDataModelName")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { [weak self] (_, error) in
        if let self = self,
            let error = error as NSError? {
            print("error!")
        }
    })
    return container
}()
```

I'm using `newBackgroundContext` to make sure any CRUD operation with `CoreData` can be done safely, regardless what thread attempts to make changes on the `managedContext`, instead of making sure or forcing each operation is done on main thread.

I have a `saveContext` method where I try to perform save operation on `managedContext` inside `performAndWait` block as following:

```
managedContext.performAndWait {
    do {
        guard UIApplication.shared.isProtectedDataAvailable,
            managedContext.hasChanges else {
            return
        }
        try managedContext.save()
    } catch {
        print("error!")
    }
}
```

It looks like `performAndWait` is most of the time runs on main thread but when it is run on another thread, the thread checker generates a warning for following check `UIApplication.shared.isProtectedDataAvailable` since it should be done on main thread.

I decided to run a selector on main thread for this check so I declared a `isProtectedDataAvailable` Bool by defaulting it to false at class level and then update its value when this selector runs.

```
@objc private func checker() {
     isProtectedDataAvailable = UIApplication.shared.isProtectedDataAvailable
}
```

Now I refactored the `performAndWait` block as following to run the check on main thread if it is called from another thread.

```
managedContext.performAndWait {
    do {        
        if Thread.isMainThread {
            checker()
        } else {
            print("RUNNING ON ANOTHER THREAD")
            Thread.current.perform(#selector(checker),
                                   on: Thread.main,
                                   with: nil,
                                   waitUntilDone: true,
                                   modes: nil)
        }

        guard isProtectedDataAvailable,
            managedContext.hasChanges else {
            return
        }
        try managedContext.save()
    } catch {
        print("error!")
    }
}
```

It seems to be working fine when I run it on simulator or real device, I generate different core data related operations which would trigger saving context both on main and background threads.

But what happens is, if I put some breakpoints inside `performAndWait` block and stop execution to examine how the code block is working, it sometimes results in application freeze when I continue execution, like a deadlock occurs. I wonder if it is somehow related to stopping execution with breakpoints or something is wrong with my implementation even though it is working fine without breakpoints, no app freeze or anything.

I'm worried because before going with this solution, I tried synchronizing on main thread by the inspiration from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60168915/8447312) to just switch to main thread to make this check, as following (which resulted in app freeze and I assume a deadlock) inside `performAndWait` block:

```
var isProtectedDataAvailable = false

if Thread.isMainThread {
    isProtectedDataAvailable = UIApplication.shared.isProtectedDataAvailable
} else {
    DispatchQueue.main.sync {
        isProtectedDataAvailable = UIApplication.shared.isProtectedDataAvailable
    }
}
```

I had to use `sync` instead of `async`, because I had to retrieve updated value of `isProtectedDataAvailable` before proceeding execution.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your question is about the right approach so that the code is working fine and it allows to set any breakpoints without running into deadlocks. :)

Why not try it this way (from what you stated i cannot see reasons against it):

1. First evaluating `UIApplication.shared.isProtectedDataAvailable` on the main thread. (I guess that there are more complex conditions that must hold not only `UIApplication.shared.isProtectedDataAvailable = true`, but to keep it simple ...)
2. If `UIApplication.shared.isProtectedDataAvailable` (and *otherConditions*) evaluates as `true` continue with data processing and saving on background thread. As `managedContext` was created as a `newBackgroundContext` it can be used there.

**Instructions on main thread**

```
    if UIApplication.shared.isProtectedDataAvailable && otherConditions {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            dataProcessing()
        }
    }
```

**Instructions on background thread**

```
    static func dataProcessing() {
       // get the managedContext
       let context = AppDelegate.appDelegate.managedContext
       context.performAndWait {
          if context.hasChanges {
             do {             
                try context.save()
             } catch {
                print("error!")
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Although this answer does not directly answer my concerns, it gave me another point of view to further explore and try things out, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, moving the following check and synchronising with main queue outside of the `performAndWait` solves all the problems.

No deadlock or app freeze occurs either with break points or without, regardless which thread triggers the method which contains `performAndWait`

So the method body looks like following now:

```
var isProtectedDataAvailable = false
if Thread.isMainThread {
    isProtectedDataAvailable = UIApplication.shared.isProtectedDataAvailable
} else {
    DispatchQueue.main.sync {
        isProtectedDataAvailable = UIApplication.shared.isProtectedDataAvailable
    }
}

managedContext.performAndWait {
    do {
        guard isProtectedDataAvailable,
        managedContext.hasChanges else {
            return
        }
        try managedContext.save()
    } catch {
        print("error")
    }
}
```